# My screen flickers at 1280 x 1024

Tags: windows-7, display

My screen flickers at 1280 x 1024, 75 hertz, 32 bit color, Dell Monitor e190s 19 inch square monitor. This problem only at the above mentioned resolution , it works fine with other resolutions. I just bought this Monitor 2 days back, do  you think the Monitor is defective ? Why is this problem occurring , the system says this is the recommended resolution. Can it be due to my graphic Card ATI xpress 200, 256 MB (in built).

Pentium 4
Windows 7 32 bit OS

Comment: It's possible that it's your screen card. What happens if you run it at a lower refresh rate?

Comment: I tried but the problem continues...it only stop when I change the resolution..

Comment: @Randolph The problem is solved when I change the refresh rate to 70 hertz, but why is it not supporting 60 and 75 hertz ?

Comment: No idea. LCD screens don't really care about refresh rates, so I'd stick it out with 70Hz and just make a note of it.

Comment: @Randolph okk is their any problem with lcd monitor or graphic card?

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with your rig, I think it's just not quite compatible at the recommended refresh rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reducing the refresh rate, right click on desktop and select screen resolution from the menu, then click on the advanced setting button and choose monitor form the tab. Try reducing the refresh rate to 60 Hz.

Comment: Yes I have tried all this ..its not working..

Comment: works fine only with 70 hertz